# I can't display "11e5" as it is on Excel spreadsheet using PHP

Tags: php, excel, mysqli

I am exporting data to a CSV file, but there is a value "**11e5**" that is getting interpreted as a number by Excel. Instead of the text, it shows **1.10E+06** on the Excel spreadsheet.

I've tried prefixing the value with an apostrophe, but then it shows up as **1100000** in Excel.

Here is the code I'm using to test, the live code gets data from MySQL.

```
function array2csv(array &$array)
{
  if (count($array) == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  ob_start();
  $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
  fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
  foreach ($array as $row) {
     fputcsv($df, $row);
  }
  fclose($df);
  return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename){
  $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
  header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
  header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Type: application/download");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

$row1 = array ('Assignment name', 'tet4' );
$row2 = array ('Class name','11e5' );
$row3 = array ('Name', 'Target', 'Start grade', 'End Grade', 'Avarage grade', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August','06th Aug', '13th Aug', '20th Aug', '27th Aug', '03rd Sep', 'Last 7 days', 'Last 24 hours',  'Total points' );
$row4 = array ('Maan Roy',  2, 1,  1,  0,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 6,  0,  32 );
$row5 = array (  'mac mac',  0, 1,  2,  1.5,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  98,  0,  98 );

$response = array(); 

array_push($response, $row1);
array_push($response, $row2);
array_push($response, $row3);
array_push($response, $row4);
array_push($response, $row5);
download_send_headers("data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($response);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your code.

Comment: Added codes and my result

Comment: I added the php codes you can run it, and see the export result. I need "11e5" OR "11E5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code to output the value like `="11e5"` and it should work fine. Tested with Excel 2016 on a Mac, but behaviour should be the same on Windows.

See this [post on SU](https://superuser.com/a/862117/127429).

Comment: I used it. `$headline2[2] = '"'.$row['class_name'] . '"';`

Comment: Ok, I tried that and still got scientific notation.

Comment: If I’m right then you should probably be changing the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

11e5 (11 × 10<sup>5</sup>) represents a number around 1100000.
Excel chooses for a different way to represent the same number. 1.10E+06 (1.10 × 10<sup>6</sup>) indeed represents the same number.
If you make the column holding the cell wider, it might even show 1100000 in Excel.

But for you 11e5 is a string indicating the name of the class. So as per CSV try putting the value in double quotes `"` to indicate the value is a string. Or as per Excel, try putting an apostrophe `'` in front of the value, to indicate the value is a string.

Comment: You are right but I am retrieving data from mysqli database. When I use that value (11e5) in array and use an apostrophe " ' " in front of it. The output is correct iin Excel. But when I use that value from database and use an apostrophe " ' " in front of it. The output is same as before (1100000).

Comment: @Leo How did you put the apostrophe in front of the value? Like this? `$row2 = array ('Class name','\'11e5');` And did you also try putting the value in double quotes `$row2 = array ('Class name','"11e5"');` ?

Comment: `$headline2[2] =  "'".$row['class_name'];` this is from database

Comment: @Leo So try it like `$headline2[2] = '"'.$row['class_name'] . '"';`

Comment: I have used that. Still, I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file format does not explicitly support meta-data, and MSExcel has a very annoying habit of assuming that anything which looks like a number is a number (it also strips off leading zeros and may insert commas). And to add insult to injury, it changes the data rather than just rendering it differently.

In a manual import, you can override this behaviour by specifying a type of 'TEXT' for the column - but that's not a great solution.

If you want a seamless user experience then you'll need to use a different format than CSV (or not use MSExcel?). You can write XML using the standard tools and there are libs for generating a file similar to an xlsx (although IME, MSExcel usually complains the latter are still in the wrong format even though it will load and render the data as intended).